# Rails 2.2 not using active record session, even though it's defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

After moving an existing rails 2.2 app to a new server, the app is now using a cookie session instead of an active record session. The old server is still running using the same repo and an active record session.

The session_store is being set properly in environment.rb and we can see Rails is loading the setting in Rails.configuration.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure about the version? 2.2 was released [10 years ago](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/2.2.2).

Comment: oh yeah, rails 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, there is a compatibility issue with rails 2.2 and phusion passenger 5. The solution is to upgrade to rails 2.3 or downgrade to passenger 4.